# student-t asset path

Tags: returns, matlab, distribution, asset

I am trying to simulate an asset path based on a t-distribution. I found a lot of ressources and the fact that it will be difficult to do a path. But now I changed my Geometric Brownian Motion Simulation and instead of using normal random numbers, I take random student-t numbers using the Matlab-command trnd. So I get a new path and the increments are student-t distributed. Now I don't know if this is a totally wrong approach, since I am more or less a beginner in quantitative finance.

Thank you for your help
Kind regards

Comment: If you just want to have a simulation it is ok, but you can no more apply the theories and applications about brownian motion.

Comment: Read this answer: http://quant.stackexchange.com/a/23295/16991

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we usually use normal distribution and not Laplace distribution to generate stochastic process?](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/23291/why-do-we-usually-use-normal-distribution-and-not-laplace-distribution-to-genera)